# Why does minimizing $H[f] =\sum^{N}_{i=1}(y_i-f(x_i))^2+\lambda \| Pf \|^2 $ leads to solution of the form $ f(x) =\sum^N_{i=1}c_iG(x; x_i)+p(x)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations, machine-learning

I was reading [the following paper of dimensionality reduction (1)](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-1167.pdf) and also one [on theory of networks for approximations and learning (2)](ftp://publications.ai.mit.edu/ai-publications/pdf/AIM-1140.pdf) and was trying to understand how the regularization problem leads to the form of the predictor function $f$.

In other words, I was trying to fully understand the details of how if one tries to minimize the functional:

$$ H[f] = \sum^{N}_{i=1} (y_i - f(x_i))^2 + \lambda \| Pf \|^2 $$

why the solution of the variational problem has the following simple form:

$$ f(x) = \sum^N_{i=1} c_i G(x ; x_i) + p(x)$$

where $G(x)$ is the Green's function of the self-adjoint differential operator $\hat{P}P$, $\hat{P}$ being the adjoint operator of P, $p(x)$ is a linear combination of functions that span the null space of $P$, and the coefficients $c_i$ satisfy a linear system of equations that depend on the $N$ "examples", i.e. the data to be approximated.

Why is it that that it has to be a linear combination of the Green's function? Why does the Green's function matter in this case?

I think they try to explain try to explain it on the second paper (2) but I didn't really understand the details. If someone understood the details better, I would be extremely grateful if they would explain it to me.

To understand this I was going through the following videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4U3P0LcaJcw&index=27&list=PL4C6F6B595A5852E8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6n0uINcvx_E&index=28&list=PL4C6F6B595A5852E8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cE4ZWo3pcCk&index=29&list=PL4C6F6B595A5852E8

I think they explain it there too but I was having some issue understanding everything. I am still in the process of going through these videos but I will add additional details as they come up through the derivation.

Comment: related question but asks for a much simpler derivation than the general one asked in the above question. Simpler question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897266/how-does-one-derive-radial-basis-function-rbf-networks-as-the-smoothest-interp